# How to move code from App.js to Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I have a small amount of js in the app.js file that I needed in order to manipulate the DOM in this Angular Grid:
http://plnkr.co/PXRgUA
You can see it in app.js.

```
$('.userRow ').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('span.userDetailRow.blueRow').show().animate({height:200},500);

});

$('.closeDetails').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('span').animate({height:0}, 500).animate({height:0},500).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

How can I move this to a directive? 
Does it have to be moved to a directive?
It does not seem right here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can (and should) move it to a directive. For the sake of clarity I'll include your old code here:

```
   $('.userRow ').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('span.userDetailRow.blueRow').show().animate({height:200},500);

});

$('.closeDetails').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent('span').animate({height:0}, 500).animate({height:0},500).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This (binding event listeners with jquery) is what people are chomping at the bit to describe as 'not the angular way.' Instead, you can use ng-click (which is just an inbuilt directive) to call javascript functions:

```
<tr row ng-click="expandRow()" ng-repeat="user in users" class="item-in-list el userRow" animate="fadeIn">

<span class="userDetailRow blueRow" style="display:none;"><span close ng-click="closeDetails(); $event.stopPropagation()">x</span>
```

You can see here there are two custom attributes defined on these elements. These link to the directives below. These directives have custom functions defined in their link function which you can then call with ng-click (though note that this is putting these functions on the global scope).

```
.directive('close', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.closeDetails = function() {
              $(element).parent('span').animate({height:0}, 500).animate({height:0},500).hide();
            }
        }
    }
})

.directive('row', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.expandRow = function() {
        $(element).find('span.userDetailRow.blueRow').show().animate({height:200},500);
      }

    }
  }
});
```

jQuery is still being used to here to locate and modify the elements for the sake of simplicity, so you can see where your old logic has gone. However you should ideally change this to use angular's inbuilt animation functionality. (more info on how animation works in the new angular version: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)

Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UMvYnx?p=preview

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome explanation and I am very appreciative for it.  I've taken tutorials and even bought a couple of books on Angular and this was the best written tutorial I've seen on converting code to a directive and why it should be done.